# Processing JSON in spark - different schemas in different files

Tags: json, apache-spark, schema

I have a large amount of JSON files obtained from 3rd party. They all have the same schema, except when a nested element is empty, it is represented as empty array.

1st example

```
{
....
"survey_data":
    {
        "2": { "question":"....", "answer_id":"....", .... },
        "3": { "question":"....", "answer_id":"....", .... },
    }
 }
```

So this is a valid JSON, the "survey_data" element is a struct_type, but with pretty complicated nested structure (with more sub-elements than in this simplified example)

However, when the survey_data has no nested elements, it is represented as empty array:

```
{
....
"survey_data": []
 }
```

which is obviously schematically incompatible, but I cannot affect this since the data is from 3rd party.

When I want to load these JSON files in spark as single dataframe, spark infers the survey_data type as string, and escapes all the characters:

```
"survey_data":"{\"2\":{\"question\": ...
```

This is obviously not good for me, I see 2 approaches how to deal with this:

1. somehow pre-process the files as pure text and remove [] characters ?
2. use spark to remove the array chars, or to tell spark that the column should be a struct type ?

Anybody able to hint me with a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, did it a long time ago.

If you have a JSON file with schema you are happy with, preferably a small one, you can use its schema to read all other JSON files:

```
val jsonWithSchema = spark.read.json("PATH_TO_JSON_WITH_RIGHT_SCHEMA")
val df = spark.read.schema(jsonWithSchema.schema).json("PATH_TO_DATAFILES")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. unfortunately my JSON schema is too large/dynamic. In some files there are a lot of nested elements and spark creates a huge json schema for the whole dataframe, which is perfectly correct except for this one field.

Comment: You can select a file that has all the fields that you need or augment it and store it separately in path PATH_TO_JSON_WITH_RIGHT_SCHEMA and always use it to infer the right schema (first line of the solution), than use that inferred schema to read all other files, the **spark.read.schema(jsonWithSchema.schema).json** should force the right schema on the files that have the one field as bad one. Try it and let me know how it works out.

Comment: I have the same problem, but in a partitioned file system, I would need to load every json since a single path :( so this solution doesn't work for me.